# responsive gallery image size

Tags: css, wordpress, image

I have a Wordpress site with some galleries with quadrangular photos but I want them to be rectangular to users see the entire photo. I changed the values (height in particular) but when I do that the image stretches and I can't find the way to resolve that problem. I'm still a little newbie in CSS so anyone can help me? It's seems to be a easy thing but unfortunately I can't do.

Here is the gallery: http://cp58.webserver.pt/~httpfash/kids/

All the images have the same size.

Some of the code:
**bootstrap-light.min.css**

```
.img-responsive {display:block;max-width:100%;height:242px}

.models li a img {
  width:100%;
```

I used firebug to find that.

Answer (score 0):

```
.models li a img {
width: 100%;
height: auto !important;
}
```

Always use height auto for responsive images

```
img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say that i only want to change the thumbnails size to rectangular. When you click in the image she goes to another page

Thank you for your response